# Combining count queries which has different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to combine my multiple count queries into one however I do not know what would be the best way to do it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id as test_count_1 
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id
RIGHT JOIN network_status_logs AS nsl ON nsl.network_id = n.id
WHERE n.status = "LIVE" AND nsl.status = 'LIVE' AND nsl.status_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING COUNT(nl.id) = 0 ;


SELECT DISTINCT n.id as test_count_2
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id
WHERE n.status = 'LIVE' AND nl.type = "ENTRENCE" AND nl.status_code = 0 AND ns.start_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59' AND ns.end_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59' AND nl.created_at BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING COUNT(nl.id) >= 1;
```

I myself tried to do something like this(but it seems to be wrong because the HAVING COUNT seems to do different action. And I do not know how to use HAVING COUNT inside COUNT(CASE WHEN)):

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN then 1 else 0 end) as test_count_1,
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN then 1 else 0 end) as test_count_2
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id
RIGHT JOIN network_status_logs AS nsl ON nsl.network_id = n.id
```

How should I combine them into one query? These queries have different WHERE and HAVING COUNT conditions but they use same tables. Any help is appreciated

So I would like to see result like:

```
test_count_1    test_count_2
           2               8
```

Comment: Why are you calling `n.id` a count?  the question is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because at the end of the query I do have GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT. And I think you can answer to the question even if you say I shouldn't select `n.id` as a count value.. This is why I am asking a question..

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you really want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT n.id) as total_n_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN nl.id IS NULL THEN n.id END) as test_count_1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN nl.id IS NOT NULL AND nl.type = 'ENTRENCE' THEN n.id END) as test_count_2
FROM networks n INNER JOIN 
     network_sessions ns
     ON ns.network_id = n.id LEFT JOIN
     network_logs nl
     ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id LEFT JOIN
     network_status_logs nsl
     ON nsl.network_id = n.id AND
        nsl.status = 'LIVE' AND
        nsl.status_time >= '2020-07-01' AND
        nsl.status_time < '2020-08-01'
WHERE n.status = 'LIVE'
```

Just move the common conditions to the `ON` or `WHERE` clauses and the specific conditions to the `CASE` expressions.

Comment: You did get the point what I want to achieve but the point is that for both queries the where condition may be different. For example I will write next count and it may have where condition with nsl.deleted_at IS NOT NULL or somehting like that. And in this case if I would include the last conditions, other counts would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation

```
    SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN n.status = "LIVE" AND nsl.status = 'LIVE' AND nsl.status_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59' then 1 end) as test_count_1,
    SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN n.status = 'LIVE' AND nl.type = "ENTRENCE" AND nl.status_code = 0 AND ns.start_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59' 
AND ns.end_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59' 
AND nl.created_at BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59' then 1 end) as test_count_2
    FROM networks as n
    INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
    LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id
    RIGHT JOIN network_status_logs AS nsl ON nsl.network_id = n.id
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for however the result is different than the queries alone give.. I always need to return count of networks but it seems to return bigger numbers than queries alone.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp, could you please add some sample data in your question

Comment: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e3739e283b0e40aa9c21a6c62d94b852) is the example table created.

Comment: It seems that the RIGHT JOIN at the end of query ruins everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
        select  pivote.test_count_1,pivote.test_count_2

        from (
        SELECT 'test_count_1' as test_count_name ,
        n.id as count_id
        FROM networks as n
        INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
        LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id
        RIGHT JOIN network_status_logs AS nsl ON nsl.network_id = n.id
        WHERE n.status = "LIVE" AND nsl.status = 'LIVE' AND nsl.status_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY n.id
        HAVING COUNT(nl.id) = 0 
        union all

        SELECT 'test_count_2' as test_count_name,
        n.id as count_id
        FROM networks as n
        INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
        LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id
        WHERE n.status = 'LIVE' AND nl.type = "ENTRENCE" AND nl.status_code = 0 AND ns.start_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59' AND ns.end_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59' AND nl.created_at BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY n.id
        HAVING COUNT(nl.id) >= 1
        ) as main
        pivot(
        COUNT(count_id) 
            FOR test_count_name IN ([test_count_1],[test_count_2])

        ) as pivote;
```